# Mailtrap does not show the body of the message

Tags: laravel

The function here is to send a six digit pin to email so as to recover password. Mailtrap inbox does not show the six digit pin, just a "button text". How do you send the recovery code /pin to the recovery mail.

```
class UserPasswordPin extends Mailable {

use Queueable, SerializesModels;

public $pin;

public function __construct($pin)
{
    $this->pin = $pin;
}


public function build()
{
    return $this->markdown('emails.userpin')->with([
        'pin' => $this->pin,
    ]);
}
```

}

The recover password controller send the six digit code. it works in postman but when it send email to mailtrap its blank. And also is there an algorithm for the method unwantedPin, like it selects a six digit conbination and prevents sending digits which are predictable?

```
class RecoverPasswordController extends Controller{

private $unwantedPins = [
    111111,222222,333333,444444,555555,666666,777777,888888,999999
];

private function inUnWanted($pin)
{
    return in_array($pin,$this->unwantedPins);
}

public function recover(RecoverPasswordRequest $request){
//check if email exist
    $user = DB::table('users')->where([
        'email' => $request->email
    ])->first();
    if (is_null($user)){
        return response([
            'errors'=>'The email entered is not registered'
        ],404);
    }

    //send a six digit code/pin to the recovery email
    $pin = rand( 111111,999999);
    foreach ($this->unwantedPins as $unwantedPin){
        if ($pin == $unwantedPin){
            $pin = rand(111111,999999);
        }
    }
    Mail::to($user)->queue(new UserPasswordPin($pin));
    return response([
        'pin'=>$pin,
        'message'=>'a six digit code has been sent to your email'
    ],200);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in userpin.blade.php

```
@component('mail::message')
# Introduction
This is your six digit number.
@component('mail::button', ['url' => ''])
{{$pin}}
@endcomponent
Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```